# HTML / CSS table with GRIDLINES

Tags: html, css, gridlines

how do I display the gridlines in a HTML table?  (am using IE6)

Comment: What do you mean by gridlines?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Via css. Put this inside the `<head>` tag.

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">

table{
border-collapse:collapse;
border:1px solid #FF0000;
}

table td{
border:1px solid #FF0000;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Use <style type="text/css"> instead.

Comment: the border-collapse on tds is superfluous (and in fact not standard).

Comment: one more question - how do I make the vertical lines solid, and the horizontal lines dashed?

Comment: border-left: 1px solid black;
border-right:1px solid black;
border-bottom:1px dotted black ( or dashed)

Comment: Useful for figuring out layout problems!

Answer (score 27):

```
<table border="1"></table>
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Should work, but it's better to separate content and design (content in html, design in css, where border is design.

Comment: Agreed, but sometimes it's ok to bend the rules a little too :)

Comment: This is great for troubleshooting when using colspan a lot. Being able to add or remove border='1' is much simpler than messing with css.

Comment: This only displays a border around the table, right? So there's no distinction between columns and rows.

Comment: @EricDuminil this is a very old answer and browsers may render differently these days. Back then most (all?) browsers would cascade the property to table elements.

Answer (score 1):

For internal gridlines, use the tag: td
For external gridlines, use the tag: table