# Displaying information in a grid on my ASP.NET MVC page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, grid-layout

There is a "Weekly Monitoring tool" on the intranet I'm working on that displays the following information (supposedly) in a grid : the company, the employee (name), his expected work time, and his current weekly activity.

The Data is saved and filtered week by week, it's all sent to my `WeeklyMonitoring.aspx` view.

The issue is that I can't seem to find a way to display it as a grid, cleanly, separating each information to make it easier to read.

Here is the relevant part of my View :

```
<table width="300" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Employee</th>
        <th>Expected Time</th>
        <th>Activity</th>
    </tr>

    <%            
    int i = 0;
    foreach (var name in ViewBag.Names)
    {
        if ((string)ViewBag.Names[i] != null)
        { %>  

            <td><%= (string)ViewBag.Company[i]%></td>
            <td><%= (string)ViewBag.Names[i]%></td>
            <td> --- </td>
            <td><%= (string)ViewBag.RecTime[i]%></td>           
      <%} %>
            <%i++; %>         
    <%      
    }
    %>

</table>
```

It does display it as a board, separating the information by spaces, how may I create a clean looking **grid** as it is supposed to be?

Comment: If you want your table to look like a grid, you need to apply styling to it.  EG http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763032/html-css-table-with-gridlines

Comment: Are you missing <tr> in your foreach?

Comment: Just adding to what @Mahbubur said, JQuery Datatables is something you should definitiely consider, for more information check out http://www.datatables.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JQuery DataTables** in an awesome plugin for this and it's very **simple** to use. **First,** add the plugin:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.css">      
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>     
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

then **Format** the table properly:

```
<table id ="table_id" class="display">
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Company</th>
          <th>Employee</th>
          <th>Expected Time</th>
          <th>Activity</th>
       </tr>
  </thead>   

<%            
int i = 0;
foreach (var name in ViewBag.Names)
{
   <tr>
    if ((string)ViewBag.Names[i] != null)
    { %>  

        <td><%= (string)ViewBag.Company[i]%></td>
        <td><%= (string)ViewBag.Names[i]%></td>
        <td> --- </td>
        <td><%= (string)ViewBag.RecTime[i]%></td>           
  <%} %>
        <%i++; %>    
 </tr>     
<% } %>
```

Now, **apply** the DataTable properties on the table:

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#table_id').DataTable();
    });
</script>
```

and see the charm.

Comment: This is marvelous, thanks you ! Would there be a way to add vertical lines between each columns though?

Comment: yes. you have to add additional css for that like `<style>table,td {    border: 1px solid gray;}</style>`. welcome :)